# Docker compose environment variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile

I'm trying to containerize a **demo** nodejs + reactjs + postgresql application and the directory structure looks something like this:

```
demo:
  -client
    -.env
    - Dockerfile.client
    - package.json
  -server
    - .env
    - Dockerfile.server
    - package.json
  .env
  docker-compose.yml
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  client:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_fe
    build:
      dockerfile: ./client/Dockerfile.client
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    image: ${APP_NAME}_img_fe
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

  server:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_be
    build:
      # context: .
      dockerfile: ./server/Dockerfile.server
    image: ${APP_NAME}_img_be
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 5000:5000

  db:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_db
    image: postgres
    build:
      # context: .
      dockerfile: ./server/Dockerfile.db
    env_file: ./server/.env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${APP_NAME}
    volumes:
    - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
      
volumes:
  db-data:
    name: ${APP_NAME}_db
```

I'm trying to keep all the sensitive data(like passwords and keys), api urls or ports inside .env files so i have all the infos in just one place, something like this:

**.env from server**

```
PORT=5000
DB_PASSWORD=postgres
DB_USER=postgres
DB_NAME=demo
```

**.env on root level**

```
APP_NAME=demo
```

The problem is for the db service (postgres container) the credentials are not visible at the creation time, so i need to hardcode them like:

```
environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: demo
```

Is there a way to fetch these values from inside the .env files ?

LE: I think one way is to keep only one .env at the root of the application with:
-db password
-db user
-port(both server and client)
-api url

In this case i need to acces .env from client and server folder.

Not sure this is a common practice or not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to access the .env file from your applications. You can substitute variables in the docker-compose.yml parsing context by simply running the `docker-compose up` in the right folder.

The issue that you're running through is probably because you have multiple .env files distributed across your project, with different values.

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files):

> If you have multiple environment variables, you can substitute them by providing a path to your environment variables file. **By default, the docker-compose command will look for a file named `.env` in the directory you run the command.** By passing the file as an argument, you can store it anywhere and name it appropriately, for example, .env.ci, .env.dev, .env.prod. Passing the file path is done using the --env-file option:

That means that not only it's a good practice to keep .env files but also that you probably should keep only one `.env` file and run the `docker-compose up` command from the folder that keeps that file (usually the project root folder).

Comment: I forgot to add that i'm in a team where some collegues don't use docker and the ormconfig.json from server has something like this for database credentials: process.env.DB_PASSWORD. In this case i need to fetch the password from .env

Comment: Isn't viable to keep one single .env file so that both the process and the docker-compose import?

Answer (score -1):

it seems to me that at your environment, '-' this symbol is missing. So it would be

```
environment:
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    - POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
    - POSTGRES_DB: ${APP_NAME}
```

and keep docker-compose.yaml and .env file under the same directory and try

docker-compose up -d

I always use -d to start as background job, daemon thread.

Also you can see the list of environment variables of Postgres at this link:

https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Comment: The docker-compose accepts both a dictionary and a list of strings for its environment variables. Also, I think you missed OP’s point